# Problem from Herstein's Topics in Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a group in which, for some integer $n > 1$, $(ab)^n = a^nb^n$
for all $a, b ∈ G$. Show that
(a) $G(n) = \{x^n | x ∈ G\}$ is a normal subgroup of $G$.
(b) $G(n- 1) = \{x^{(n- 1)} | x ∈ G\}$ is a normal subgroup of $G$.

I have been trying this for a long time but not been able to make any progress.
This should be a basic question, but I got no clue... Please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$G(i)$ is normal for all $i$, so it remains to check that they are closed under multiplication.

If $x^n, y^n \in G(n)$, then $x^n y^n = (xy)^n \in G(n)$, so indeed $G(n)$ is a subgroup.

For $x^{n-1}, y^{n-1} \in G(n-1)$, $x^{n-1} y^{n-1} = x^{-1} x^n y^n y^{-1} = x^{-1} (xy)^n y^{-1} = (yx)^{n-1} \in G(n-1)$.

Comment: How to show G(i) is normal for for all i ?

Comment: If $x^i \in G(i)$ then $gx^ig^{-1} = (gxg^{-1})^i \in G(i)$

Comment: i guess g.x^i.g−1 ∈ G(i) means that g.x^i.g−1 = y^i for some y ∈ G

Comment: This is where I'am stuck

Comment: $gx^i g^{-1} = (gxg^{-1})^i$

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot : )